# Matlab Arduino Using analog inputs as outputs

Tags: matlab, arduino

I need to use Arduino analog inputs as digital outputs which are A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5.
Normally digitalWrite(A0, 0) is doing its job  when i use arduino program however in matlab i couldnt find a way to do this.I tried if A0 is taken as 14 digitalWrite(14, 0) and didnt work.
Do you know how to do this pin mapping thing in Matlab? Briefly what is the equal of digitalWrite(A0, 0) in matlab?

```
 function test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% Choose default command line output for test
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

global a;
set(handles.pushbutton1, 'UserData', 0);
a=arduino('COM3');

a.pinMode(2,'output');
a.pinMode(3,'output');
a.pinMode(4,'output');
a.pinMode(5,'output');
a.pinMode(6,'output');
a.pinMode(7,'output');
a.pinMode(8,'output');
a.pinMode(9,'output');
a.pinMode(10,'output');
a.pinMode(11,'output');
a.pinMode(12,'output');
a.pinMode(13,'output');
a.pinMode(14,'output');
```

---

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global a;
global counter;
counter = get(hObject, 'UserData') + 1
set(hObject, 'UserData', counter);

if(counter==1)
a.digitalWrite(14,1);This doesnt work
a.digitalWrite(7, 0);
a.digitalWrite(13, 0); 
a.digitalWrite(8, 1); 
a.digitalWrite(12, 0);
a.digitalWrite(9,0); 
a.digitalWrite(11, 0);
a.digitalWrite(10, 0);

  a.servoStatus(2)
end
```

Comment: Please format your [inline code with backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) correctly or write [code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

You were right in assuming that A0 is equivalent to pin 14, so your code should work. Perhaps you forgot to set the pin mode? Can you post your code and the error you got?

The following code works for me:

```
 a = arduino('COM4');
 a.pinMode(14,'output'); % pin 14 is equivalent to analog pin A0

 tic;
 while toc/60 < 0.25 % Run for 15 seconds
    a.digitalWrite(14,1); % setting A0 to HIGH
 end

 delete(a);
 clear a;
```

Comment: I updated my code and i know for pin 8 its working.Its not my all code it just counting the button push number and actually show that numbers on 7 segment display.When i use A0 its not working(Normally its working using just Arduino).Also my microprocessor is Arduino-Leonardo.In matlab support rar i uploaded adioes.pde to arduino.